# Pandas Merging rows and summing values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have some earthquake data. I have a Magnitude, Distance, and Percent that I care about. I want to **group all of the MAGNITUDES together and sum** the distances and percents for each magnitudes. Here is a part of my data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Distance': [1, 5, 9, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3.1],
        'Magnitude': [7.3, 7.3, 7.3, 6.0, 8.2, 6.0, 8.2, 5.7],
        'Percent': [0.1, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.2, 0.07, 0.08,0.11]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)


         Distance  Magnitude  Percent
 0       1.0        7.3     0.10
 1       5.0        7.3     0.05
 2       9.0        7.3     0.07
 3       3.0        6.0     0.11
 4       5.0        8.2     0.20
 5       4.0        6.0     0.07
 6       2.0        8.2     0.08
 7       3.1        5.7     0.11
```

My idea was this. Groupby and sum:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Distance','Magnitude','Percent'],as_index=False).agg({'Percent': 'sum'},{'Distance': 'sum'})
```

I get the same dataframe upon running my code except it is ascending by distance which is fine, but nothing groupped together or summed.

I want it to look like this:

```
       Distance  Magnitude  Percent
0      15.0        5.7     0.22
1       7.0        6.0     0.18
2       7.0        7.3     0.28
3       3.1        8.2     0.11
```

There is only 1 value for each magnitude and the distances and percents have been summed for each magnitude.

Comment: you want to group only on Magnitude, not the three columns, so do `df.groupy('Magnitude').agg...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the the task, you just need to groupby magnitude only

```
df.groupby(by=["Magnitude"]).sum()
```

Output

```
           Distance  Percent
Magnitude                   
5.7             3.1     0.11
6.0             7.0     0.18
7.3            15.0     0.22
8.2             7.0     0.28
```

Or to prevent Magnitude becoming an index as per @lsr729 you can use this as well

```
df.groupby(by=["Magnitude"], as_index=False).sum()
```

Output2

```
   Magnitude  Distance  Percent
0        5.7       3.1     0.11
1        6.0       7.0     0.18
2        7.3      15.0     0.22
3        8.2       7.0     0.28
```

Comment: You can also add `as_index=False`  in groupby to prevent Magnitude to be an index